# Slow iOS Simulator all of a sudden, toggle animations not fixing it - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

so I've been working on this app for a few weeks now and the iOS simulator has been running so smoothly and quickly. But now all of a sudden it is running so slowly I can barely test the features of the app - just a few days before I demonstrate it to my boss...

I've seen people recommend trying to Toggle Animations on and off, but this doesn't seem to be making a difference.

But I do have some animations in there.

UPDATE: fixed now, it was the sleep commands in my code.

But next question is how do I edit this code:

```
- (void)animateImages
{
  static int count = 0;
  NSArray *animationImages =@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"slide8.png"]];
  UIImage *image =
  [animationImages objectAtIndex:(count % [animationImages count])];
  [UIView transitionWithView:_imView
                  duration:1.5
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    _imView.image = image;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [self animateImages];
                    count++;
                }];
 }
```

So that each image stays on the screen for longer. The animation seems to run so quickly!

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you have accidentally turned on slow animation? (command + T)

Comment: I feel your pain, but that's about all that can be done with the question as written.  Can you form a theory about what's wrong and then try to fix by altering code, then post those experiments here in the form of a programming question?

Comment: I had a sleep command in the code for the animation and I've taken that out now and it seems to have done the trick! So the next question is:

Comment: ^^^ I'll add it into the original question

Comment: Could you show what it look like? Else, you could do `[self performSelector:@selector(animateImages) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];` instead of `[self animateImages];`.

Comment: that caused the animation to wait 2 seconds before starting, but then the images cycled through too quickly again, thanks though!